# Using httpclient Get all images url from a link

Tags: android

I have specified a URL  for bitmap to download the image using httpclient connectivity.But I have to 
get all url form the site  "http://postimg.org/gallery/5y7ulm9o/b2f8235e/" which has n number of images I have to get all the url of the images and have to store it in string array. I dont know how to do that Plz help..

```
 package de.vogella.android.bitmap.httpdownload.simple;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class DownloadExampleActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

        }

        public void downloadPicture(View view) {
            final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Download",
                    "downloading");
            dialog.show();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        final Bitmap downloadBitmap = downloadBitmap("http://postimg.org/image/iwcmlxf17");
                        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageView.setImageBitmap(downloadBitmap);
                            }
                        });

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }).start();

        }

        private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) throws IOException {
            HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url.toString());
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                byte[] bytes = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0,
                        bytes.length);
                return bitmap;
            } else {
                throw new IOException("Download failed, HTTP response code "
                        + statusCode + " - " + statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Please remove Eclipse from the Subject and also from the tags. Your problem has nothing to do with Eclipse. Your real problem (and a better subject) is that you want to parse urls from a html page you got from the web. You can use JSOUP for that.

Comment: ok I thought it would be more specific if I mention it as eclipse and will remove it from my next post. And thank u for the reply.

Comment: Please remove it from this post and rephrase subject and your question. You don't need a second post as you are not ready yet.

Comment: I have one more doubt if I use json for that I need to view the web page in jason view format. But if I inspect element it gives me the URL of of xml view format. How i can view the web page  by json format?

Comment: You cannot use json on a html source. You have to parse the html source with jsoup.